# Camera2 api set parameter in HAL3

Tags: parameters, camera2

I am a Android newbie in Camera. I have a question about how to set the vendor tag  parameter to `hal3` using camera2 api, because in the past, I used camera API 1 (HAL1) to set the parameter to HAL.

Is there any way to use Camera2 API to set custom tag's value to HAL3? Thanks!

Comment: How did you do it before in Camera API?

Comment: i just used setparameter api includeing our tag string and value , but in camera2 , i do not know how to do ,

Comment: Because in camera2 , if you want to add you vendor tag , framework will check whether it has this tag or not, cuz i do not want to modify the framework

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/package-summary.html

Comment: yes. i did, and for now i want to set qcom hal3 vendor tags with camera2 api

Comment: Well, honestly, I have no clue. But when you figure it out, could you post an answer, for the sake of Q&A repository completeness?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter can be set as part of capture request. Android provides capture request builder API to set value for each keys(parameters).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder

VendorTag can be set as similar as other parameters. App developer has to know vendorTag list that vendor provides. Same vendorTag Key(string) vendor defines has to be used to set it in Capture Request.

If app uses undefined vendorTag, app will be crashed due to "Could not find tag for key".

Answer (score 0):

Camera2 api is quite different from camera1 but still we can work on it's core parameters same like camera1 setParameter method. And it will gives you the benefits as like camera1 user friendly api. Just need to burn some molecules from memory.

Like in camera1 we have:
**params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);**

**Which can be implemented in camera2 using CaptureRequest.Builder:
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);**

And then call captureSession.setRepeatingRequest() to invalidate parameter.

Hola....Happy Coding.

You can refer complete camera2 example at google.
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic